# List s3 folders with specific nametag

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to know if we can list s3 folders with a specific name. For example I would like to list the folders in all s3 buckets labelled "darwin".

Comment: what do you mean by labelled? Do they have a bucket level tag with key as `label` ?

Comment: No. There are multiple folders with name "darwin" in multiple buckets. I was wondering if you guys can help out with boto script that checks all the folders in all the buckets and print out the folders named "darwin" -Thanks

Comment: We can help in debugging the script you have written.

Comment: Try writing it yourself -- you'll learn a lot in the process! Start by listing all buckets and printing their names. Then, for each bucket, have it retrieve a list of objects and print their keys (filenames). Once that is working, add an `if` statement to only print the name of folders that have 'darwin' in their name. If you have problems, add the code to your Question and let us know what problem you are facing.

Comment: import boto3
 client = boto3.client('s3')
 response = client.list_buckets()
 f = open("./data/darwin.csv", "w")
 titles= 'bucket names \n'
 f.write(titles)
 for bucket in response['Buckets']:
     s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
     bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
     for obj in bucket.objects.all():
         if 'darwin' in obj.key.lower():
             print(obj.key)  
             f.close()

Comment: This is the code i could come up with...the problem here is there are about 500 buckets and millions of files. So i would like to  print the buckets that it checked into a csv file.

Comment: `import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.list_buckets()
f = open("./data/jumpshot.csv", "w")
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        if 'jumpshot' in obj.key.lower():
            f.write(obj.key)  
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Sreekanth, Try this...

```
s3= boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
   for object_summary_iterator in bucket.objects.all():
       dirname= os.path.split(object_summary_iterator.key)[0]   
       if dirname: 
          if 'darwin' in dirname:
             print(object_summary_iterator.key)
```

you can pipe it to a txt file for later examinations...

Hope this helps...
r0ck